# How to use identity to find this derivative

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory, operator-algebras, calculus

The derivative of an exponential operator is [defined](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1705306):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\exp[- iH] = -i\int_0^1d\alpha \;\exp[-i(1-\alpha)H]\frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \exp[-i\alpha H].$$

What then is the following:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\exp[- iH],$$

where $H$ is a function of $m$ and $n$. This is a study of identities, and finds applications in many Physically motivated situations. My motive is to find the nth derivative of the identity given in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Duhamel's formula you already know about,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\exp[- iH] = -i\int_0^1d\alpha \;\exp[-i(1-\alpha)H]\frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \exp[-i\alpha H],$$
you simply slug through, using the chain rule and iterating the formula itself: 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\exp[- iH]=
-i\int_0^1d\alpha \;\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\exp[-i(1-\alpha)H]\frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \exp[-i\alpha H]\\ -i\int_0^1d\alpha \;\exp[-i(1-\alpha)H]\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \exp[-i\alpha H]     -i\int_0^1d\alpha \;  \exp[-i(1-\alpha)H]\frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\exp[-i\alpha H]\\ =-i\int_0^1d\alpha \;\exp[-i(1-\alpha)H]\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \exp[-i\alpha H] \\  
-\int_0^1\int_0^1d\beta \;d\alpha \;\exp[-i(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)H]~ (1-\alpha)\frac{\partial H}{\partial m}\exp[-i\beta(1-\alpha)H]\frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \exp[-i\alpha H] \\
-\int_0^1\int_0^1d\beta \;d\alpha \;\exp[-i(1-\alpha)H] \frac{\partial H}{\partial n} \exp[-i\alpha(1-\beta) H]~\alpha\frac{\partial  H}{\partial m}
\exp[-i\beta\alpha H]~.
$$
Not a pretty sight, but Magnus and Dyson expansions have this way of splattering...

You might be able to redefine your integration variables into friendlier combinations.

[This crib-sheet](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/CBH.pdf)  might be helpful.

Comment: Wow, a bit messy! I will have a look, but the crib sheet seems useful!